# Execute shell commands on Android using assest folder files

Tags: java, android, weka

I read different posts for how i can execute shell commands on Android but i didn't find exactly what i want. I want to execute the following line.

```
java -jar Run.jar traindata.arff testing.arff classifier_filename output_file
```

My problem is that ***traindata.arff*** and ***classifier_filename*** are in my assets folder. How would i say in the execute command to take this file from assets folder sn where the ***output_file*** will be stored?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: That will depend on the used Android app i think. If even it would be possible what i doubt. Which do you use?

Comment: what do you mean by which android app?

Comment: You said you were executing shell commands on Android. So which Android app/shell?

Comment: I have create my own app that i want to execute inside my code this shell command.

Comment: Ok. Nice to know. The system will not look in the assets folder of your .apk. The assets folder is not a folder on the file system but merely a resource for your app. So copy the files first to the file system. You cannot direct output to assets either.

Comment: i have to use the **getAssets()** to take it and copy it inside the app folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75130/discussion-between-nestorasg-and-greenapps).

Comment: Yes. Code for copying files from assets to file system has been posted many times on this site. App folder? Which folder do you mean? Don't know if shell can use your files from internal memory. Better export to external memory and use full paths in your script.

Comment: Not only are assets not actual files, but unless you built one with the NDK and packaged it in your app, **there is no JVM or "java" command to invoke it**.  If you want to run code built from Java source, you should first port that code to build against the Android SDK, and then call into it from the Java code of your app, rather than trying to exec it in a distinct process under either a JVM that isn't present or a DVM/ART instance that is.

Comment: ok, i have manage to copy the assest files to a folder.
now how i will execute the "java -jar" command? do i need any libraries to be added to android project?